# How would I use the lines in text file only once?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to load lines from a text file and then split them into ccnumber, month, year, cvv and then send a request to an API with them.

```
ccs = open('ccs.txt', 'r').readlines()
for line in ccs:
    Type = line.split("|")
    ccnumber = Type[0]
    month = Type[1]
    year = Type[2]
    cvv = Type[3]
```

and then sending request:

```
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

(the ccnum, month, year and cvv is in data ofcourse.)

All of this is in a while true loop. How would I make it so it only uses 1 line 1 time?

Right now it only sends a request with the last line in the text file.

Comment: Fix four indentation. The request must be done within the for loop which processes one line

Comment: It works? All of that is in a loop in a function, if you want me to I can upload the code to pastebin or something.

Comment: I don't want to read pages of code. Please provide a [mre]. Also, please use an IDE which has a decent debugger, e.g. Pycharm Community Edition. Put a breakpoint at the beginning of the for loop. Step through your code line by line and see what happens. If something happens that doesn't meet your expectations, it's 99% chance that the misunderstanding is on your side.

Comment: You dont get it. I don't get an error or anything. I am asking how I would do something. How do I make it only use 1 line that it read from a file ONCE? If I do random choice It will use other lines too but it'll repeat.

Answer (score 0):

With the given code it's a lot of guesswork to figure out what you want to achieve. I just hope that I can't be legally punished for helping you use stolen credit cards. My magic ball says your is looks like this

```py
class Data:
    ...

while (True):
    url = ...
    headers = ...
    with open('ccs.txt', 'r').readlines() as ccs:
        for line in ccs:
            Type = line.split("|")
            ccnumber = Type[0]
            month = Type[1]
            year = Type[2]
            cvv = Type[3]
            data = Data(ccnumber, month, year, cvv)
        r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

And from the comments I understand that within each iteration of the `while(True)` loop, you want to process one line of the file content only.

The problem currently is:

- the code reads the whole file in each iteration of the loop
- `data` will always contain the contents of the last line, since it will be overwritten by the for loop except for the last iteration

In that case I suggest the following:

1. read the file contents into memory only once, i.e. outside the `while (True)` loop
2. In each iteration of the `while (True)` loop, pick one item of that list and process it

It'll look like this:

```py
class Data:
    ...

filecontent = []
with open('ccs.txt', 'r').readlines() as ccs:
    for line in ccs:
        Type = line.split("|")
        ccnumber = Type[0]
        month = Type[1]
        year = Type[2]
        cvv = Type[3]
        data = Data(ccnumber, month, year, cvv)
        filecontent.append(data)

while (True):
    url = ...
    headers = ...
    data = filecontent.pop(0)  # or random, whatever you need
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```